# Fibonacci sequence - an inductive proof of its formula

Tags: induction

Prove that $$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n\right)$$  if $a_{n+1} = a_{n-1} + a_n$ 
My idea to solve this was to do what follows:

(1) Check if this relation holds for $n =1$ and $n=2$ 
(2) Assume that the formula is true for $n$ and $n-1$ 
(3) Evaluate $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$, substitute for the right hand side and try to to get 
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}\right)$$ 
After I put some work in, I carried it to this form: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{n-1} \left( \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right) -\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{n-1} \left( \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)$$

I have checked and $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}=(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2$

Is this proof formally valid?

Comment: Seems pretty good to me.....

Comment: see here http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jim/proofsch8.pdf

Comment: i hope this will help you!